# if 2 div's come close to each other - float right

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with navbar. I want navbar on dekstop to look like this: logo on the left 
few buttons(4) on the right. And on small devices like this: logo on top -> to the right, buttons below logo on the right. When i start to resize the window and it reaches certain point i set logo float to the right but as long there is empty space they wont be on top each other but buttons move to the left side and logo ti the right(tablet or portrait). Then resize reaches small window - they finally stack. So my question is if it is possible to make logo FLOAT RIGHT only then buttons come in contact and not based on media query?

example: http://lunskis.byethost9.com/lg%20-%20Copy/

try to resize and see what happens in when media query is set( logo jumps on the right, while buttons get to middle and final rezult(small window) is what I am looking for).

Comment: Why shouldn't it be based on a media query?

Comment: IF you don't want to use media query and looking at your I think you need to use JavaScript/jQuery to verify width of both (logo and ul) and manipulate your CSS. But still using media query is better and easy way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use css media queries:

```
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    /* Styles */
    #logo {
        float:right
    }
}
```

find more css media queries on:

[css media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: With media query it doesnt do what i want. Check example. It floats right alright, but if where is more space left button menu swaps to the middle. So maybe i'm missing something on css department - i dont know.

Comment: Ahh ok, so you have to add to the css, I gave you, this: ul.nav{width: 100%;}, so logo will be on right, and buttons below.